# Yii: How to populate a Select input with another model data?

Tags: yii, relational-database

I'm playing around with a small app in order to learn to use Yii.

I've created a small webapp  with  2 models / tables: Projects and tasks. (1-to-many relationship, properly configured in the model classes).

I'm now trying to customize the Task/create view, replacing the text input field with a select box proposing the list of available projects.

I opened the form view and tried this:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'project_id'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'project_id'); ?>
    <?php 
// my hack starts here
    $projects = Project::model()->findAll();
    $list = CHtml::listData($projects, 'id', 'name');
    echo $form->listBox($model,'project_id','', $list); ?>

// my hack ends here
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'project_id'); ?>
</div>
```

But it keeps throwing warnings or error (such as `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`, and definitely does not work. I'm failing to understand what i'm doing wrong. Can you help ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your arguments are not in order (it should be):

```
$frameworks = Framework::model()->findAll();
$list = CHtml::listData($frameworks, 'id', 'name');
echo $form->listBox($model,'framework_id', $list,array());
```

Check the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#listBox-detail)

Comment: btw, if the fourth argument is empty you can leave it unspecified, as  in : `$form->listBox($model,'framework_id', $list);`

Answer (score 3):

OK, i found it, thanks to [Larry Ullman excellent tutorial](http://www.larryullman.com/2009/11/12/basic-view-edits-in-yii/#more-680).

Here it is:

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'project_id', CHtml::listData(Project::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name')); ?>
```