# Call to a member function of a non-object, yii and php web development book code error

Tags: php, yii

I am looking for a solution to the problem I have when following the "Web application development with Yii and PHP 2nd Edition" books example. The error I get ( from the title ) is not supposed to show up judging by everything that is in the book. alright so this is what I am trying to do.
In a Project.php model I have defined a method which should use CHtml helper of Yii to create an "acceptable" array to use with Yii's dropDownList() method of CActiveForm ( used in the view file) . Looks like this

```
public function getUserOptions() {
    // $this->users refers to the defined relationship of this class
    $usersArray = CHtml::listData($this->users, 'id', 'username');
    return $usersArray;
}
```

The relationships are defined in the relations() method of the same class

```
public function relations() {
 // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
 // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
 return array(
    'issues' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Issue', 'project_id'),
    'users' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'User', 'tbl_project_
    user_assignment(project_id, user_id)'),
 );
}
```

and how I want to give the user a dropdown list using the getUserOptions() to generate the options in key => value pairs using the Yiis dropDownList() method, like this. The _form.php is a view file for the IssueControler.php controller, and the code for the part of the code which should generate the dropdown is this:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'owner_id'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'owner_id', $model->project-      >getUserOptions()); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'owner_id'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'requester_id'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'requester_id', $model->project->getUserOptions()); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'requester_id'); ?>
</div>
```

Like I said, _form.php renders untill it hits the first of the two dropdowns and then gets this error:

**Fatal error: Call to a member function getUserOptions() on a non-object in E:\Programi\XAMP\htdocs\trackbar\protected\views\issue_form.php on line 44**

Any help would be appreciated :) Btw, in the book it shows that everything should work...

Edit: Here is the actionCreate() method of the IssueController.php which calls this _form.php view to render, for reference.

```
public function actionCreate() {
    $model=new Issue;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Issue'])) {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Issue'];
        $model->project_id = $this->_project->id;
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Comment: Yii books has lots of error code.

Comment: Show us how the object instances are built

Comment: late , but this is the answer for the question above : click -> [stackoverflow.com/questions/10744479/yii-how-to-populate-a-select-input-with-another-model-data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744479/yii-how-to-populate-a-select-input-with-another-model-data) hope this helps everyone

Answer (score 3):

you need to get current project instance first. Than on the basis of that Project instance you can get user list for that specific project. Add this

```
public function getProject()
{
   return $this->_project;
}
```

and use this as.

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'owner_id'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'owner_id', $model->getProject()-      >getUserOptions()); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'owner_id'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'requester_id'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'requester_id', $model->getProject()->getUserOptions()); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'requester_id'); ?>
</div>
```

Hope this will work

Comment: Yeah, but then I cannot use "$this->users" in the getUserOptions() method to acces that class relationship